# memoization for recursive Longest Increasing subsequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I came up with simple following recursive solution for Longest increasing sub-sequence.
But, Can you help to include memoization into this recursive solution.

```
public int findLIS(int a[], int maxSoFar, int item, int count) {

        if(item == a.length) {
            return count;
        }
        int length1 = findLIS(a,maxSoFar, item+1, count);
        int length2 = 0;
        if(a[item] > maxSoFar) {

            length2 = findLIS(a, a[item], item+1, count + 1);
        }
        return Math.max(length1, length2);
}
```

PS: This not a homework question, it is more of my interest.

Comment: Java, but you can easily convert to your favorite language.
I can do it for you if you want

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Map<Pair<Integer,Integer>,Integer>`, and at the beginning of the method add:

```
Integer cache = map.get(new Pair<Integer,Integer>(maxSoFar,item));
if (cache != null) return cache;
```

Each time you `return` anything - make sure to write `(maxSoFar,item)=returnValue` to the map.

The idea is to map between the pair that represent where you are in the calculation - to the maximal value found for this state, to avoid recalculating it.

---

It seems java, so you can use [apache commons Pair](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.0-beta/org/apache/commons/lang3/Pair.html) as your `Pair` interface.

Comment: Thanks.Before posting here, I quickly checked with an array of { 10, 22, 9, 33, 21, 50, 41, 60, 80 }; and a memo = new int[10][81]; 

But, it didn't work for me. I'll check with your solution too.

Comment: @coder000001: It is equivalent to the map solution. Please post the code you used, there might be a bug in it

Comment: it may not equivalent. whn array gets bigger allocating memory may lead to core dump. so Map is a better soln.

Comment: here is the implementation using the map 
https://pastebin.com/BZatp7by  in case if someone is interested.